# 2010 GMC Terrain misfires & leans codes

Tags: misfire, gmc, terrain

My 2010 GMC Terrain while maintaining a speed of around 60 - 70 mph starts to hesitate and if I don't release my foot from the pedal I will get flashing check egine. I've noticed it likes to happen more when the pedal is at about 50%. I have changed a couple parts out now, but the misfiring is only coming from cylinder head number #3. I've checked for any noticeable vacuum leaks, and nothing.  I've now bought a obdII link mk+ I have readings, but nothing to compare them with. If you have any ideas, I'm willing to check it out.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is your Terrain direct injection? (I don't remember when DI came into play for the smaller vehicles.) I'd suggest you've got an injector problem either way, though. Sounds like it isn't keeping up with fuel demand.